# Bitmap decodeResource the right way?

Tags: android, android-bitmap

I use Bitmap to set image on Rect,for 2d game but when I set the Image with Bitmap, I get the following error:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference

My code set the image on the Rect is:
    canvas.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.asteroid), null, rectangle, paint);

What is the right way to avoid getting any `null object reference`?

Comment: Well `context==null` as you can conclude from the error message. Do not use a context that is null i would say.

Comment: I sreached a little bit and i found Resources.getSystem() and it's says No known package when getting value for resource number

Comment: Great. But what does it have to do with your problem?

Comment: It's show the image but after a while , and if i use Recsources.getSystem() the Rect are recycled . and i get the massage "boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.isRecycled()"